# Issue with popup calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm learning primefaces 4.0 on eclipse and I'm stuck with one calendar task I want to implement.
Currently I'm using popup calendar(for date of birth) with `navigator="true"`. Now I want to implement when a user clicks on a month or year on a calendar, to appear in the input field where we popped the popup calendar.

Comment: Why am i being downvoted, can you atleast give me some kind of explanation ?

Comment: Try to implement something and come up with a problem, here people will help you to solve your problem not write code for you.

Comment: I don't need code, just some kind of guidelines what to do/or how can i get to my goal.

Comment: I would say search some thing in google, find somethng and try it and post your problem

Comment: I already did that for 2 hours, didn't find anything similar. That is  the reason why i'm here. I understand i didn't write any code, but i explained my situation thoroughly.

Comment: Your title is too generic. You should try newer versions to see if something has changed there. If you searched and found sort of related issues but they did not help, post the links and tell why they did not solve it (as stated in [ask]. why do you need to have it appear in the input field if the user chooses 1 of the 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p:calendar id="someId" value="#{aCalendarValue}" 
    required="false"  
    size="10"
    locale="it"
    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
    navigator="true" 
    converter="primefacesCalendarConverter"
/>
```

Comment: Why this? What is the important part in this answer that makes it work?

Comment: It does exactly what was requested by Bora I think. But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I don't know, I'm not saying it does not help, but adding a little text to why or what what attribute makes the difference (`navigator= "true"` coming to mind, but that is already used as stated in the question).

Comment: I agree with you